# Zoom - CSS Just some resolution

Tags: css, wordpress, zooming

Hi I have a site its responsive, but  for this resolution the site its too big:

800x600
1024x768
1280x600
1280x720
1280x768
1360x768
1366x768

So,I put this in my CSS Aditional on wordpress

```
.container{
    zoom:0.9
}
```

But how can I limited to resolution described??

Comment: Use the metatag and you can limit the zoom, but not sure why you'd want to, this limits your site's accessibility?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are looking for are media queries, which are a css rule that uses @media set certain CSS properties depending on a device's general type (such as print vs. screen) or specific characteristics and parameters (such as screen resolution or browser viewport width).

For example, for browsers with a minumum width of 800px, apply this style:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .container{
        zoom:0.9
    }   
}
```

Comment: header{
 zoom:1.05
}

.container{
    zoom:0.84
}

footer{
 zoom:1
}

Comment: You can add whatever css properties and selectors you want inside of the media query